# Resize UICollectionView after view transition

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, autolayout

I've built detail view in Interface Builder showing informations and photos about some object. Because lenght of informations and number of photos will vary, all is nested in `UIScrollView`.

Photos are shown in `UICollectionView`, but I need to always show all contained photos, so I disabled scrolling and dynamically changing `Height` constraint of `UICollectionView` by this function (called when finishing rendering cells):

```
func resizePhotosCollectionView() {
    photosCollectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = photosCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize()
}
```

It works great until this `UICollectionView` needs resize (typically by device orientation change). I am trying to use `UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator` in function:

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition(nil) { context in
        self.resizePhotosCollectionView()
    }
    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)
}
```

but result is jerky because `Height` constraint changed after transition is complete.

Is there any way how to automatically resize `UICollectionView` after view transition? If not, how to animate `Height` constraint change during transition?

Using Xcode 6.1 for target IOS 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried wrapping your constraint update into a view animation?

```
photosCollectionViewHeightConstraint.constant =
    photosCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize()
photosCollectionView.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()

UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
    photosCollectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```

Comment: This is nearly perfect solution, especially when simultaneously call `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` and `layoutIfNeeded` on subsequent view (below `UICollectionView`). Thanks Mundi!

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, you need to layout the view immediately.

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition(nil) { context in
        self.resizePhotosCollectionView()
        self.view.setNeedsLayout()
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)
}
```